# What is the NFL record for starting field position by kick returner

Tags: american-football, statistics, nfl, records

Can anyone find the NFL record for starting field position attributed to the primary kick returner?  I've looked through several websites listing NFL records, to no avail.

Specifically looking for average starting field position after a kick-off for a whole NFL season.

Comment: Do you mean what is the longest kick return that didn't result in a touchdown? If the returner goes all the way for a touchdown there will be no starting field position

Comment: I’ve clarified above. Want to know best average starting field position after a kickoff attributed to a primary kick returner.

Comment: To make alamoot's question a bit more concrete: if a returner's season went 20 yard line, 30 yard line, 40 yard line, touchdown, what would the "average starting field position" be?

Comment: I’m not sure how they calculate starting field position in case of a TD return. Although rare. I would probably consider that 0. They do have stats on team starting position but that includes punts, turnovers and touch backs.   In your example (if we consider a TD return to be starting on the 0 TD line, the average starting position for those 4 returns would be 100-(80+70+60+0)/4 = 47.5 yard line.

Comment: Currently if a kick results in a touchback, the ball will be placed on the 25 yard line to start the next drive. So maybe 100-25=75 yards would sound reasonable for kick return resulting in a touchdown. But you could also count the total yards the returner carried the ball. Also notice that since teams start at the 25 yard line, this shifts the average starting field as well.